# force close when inflate layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I've used layout inflater in my program. Everything is good in Android 4 but when use in android 2.2, the program terminates with a runtime error (force close).

Where is the problem?

Part of the code:

```
Log.i("Hossein", "1");
    
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    
    Log.i("Hossein", "2");
    
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent,
            false);

    Log.i("Hossein", "3");
```

Layout code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            style="?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            style="?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat messages:

> 09-30 11:26:32.934: I/Hossein(416): 1
>
> 09-30 11:26:32.934: I/Hossein(416): 2
>
> 09-30 11:26:32.974: D/AndroidRuntime(416): Shutting down VM
>
> 09-30 11:26:32.974: W/dalvikvm(416): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at com.androidbegin.sidemenututorial.MenuListAdapter.getView(MenuListAdapter.java:56)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:709)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1580)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:702)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java:115)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    ... 34 more
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/list_selector_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x0
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1697)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.view.View.(View.java:1885)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.view.View.(View.java:1834)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:285)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    ... 38 more
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/list_selector_background.xml from xml type drawable resource ID #0x0
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1924)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1692)
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.034: E/AndroidRuntime(416):    ... 42 more
>
> 09-30 11:26:33.143: D/dalvikvm(416): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3421 objects / 286952 bytes in 102ms
>
> 09-30 11:26:35.735: I/Process(416): Sending signal. PID: 416 SIG: 9

Comment: can you show your list_selector_background.xml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// try this way
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              style="?android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                style="?android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subtitle"
                style="?android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`activatedBackgroundIndicator` attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#activatedBackgroundIndicator) was introduced in API level 11 (Android 3.0).

Replace the `android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"` in your root layout with something that is available on all targeted API levels, or use the [alternative resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) mechanism to variate between pre-11 and other layouts.

Note that the stacktrace mentions `list_selector_background.xml` - are you sure this is the exact code causing this stack trace?